# Create a table on HBase through Impala

Tags: hbase, cloudera, impala, bigdata

Hello I want to create database schema and some tables on HBase, I would like to do so through Impala for example

```
CREATE  TABLE media.post
(RowKey string, 
 HashTag string,
 PostID string,
 PostImpact int,
 PostSentiment string,
 CreationDateTime timestamp);
```

when I do so, I get a table created but on HDFS not on HBase, thus I cannot connect to it through HBase...is that even possible to run such sql on HBase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible..

Hbase is schema less and from Hbase you can create Impala or hive external tables.
But not in the reverse way i.e from Impala table you cant create Hbase table.
Its due to the fact that, nosql and sql datamodels are different

For more understanding [go through](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/impala/1-x/1-0-1/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_impala_hbase.html)